# python3 -m http.server con Wordpress

Tags: python, wordpress, http, server

estaba tratando de lanzar localmente un servidor web para trabajar en LAN mediante la orden `python3 -m http.server [puerto]`.

Hasta aquí todo bien, puedo lanzar localmente el servidor sin problema alguno ahora bien, este servidor sigue la estructura, digamos, "típica" de apache donde, el archivo por defecto es siempre `index.html`.

Mi problema esta en que quiero añadir en el directorio de trabajo donde ejecuto el comando anterior para iniciar el servidor un servidor Wordpress en vez de trabajar con archivos "base".

Si alguien tiene el conocimiento de saber como hacer correr un Wordpress mediante la orden anterior se lo agradecería.

Comment: Estoy activamente a la espera de comentarios en caso de necesitar aclaraciones !

Comment: Hm, un servidor HTTP cualquiera atiende eso, peticiones HTTP. Va a servir recursos que le pongas ahí en donde está el index.html. Entendería que para servir un sitio wordpress, tendrías que ponerle un procesador PHP que interprete los scripts y sirva el HTML resultante. Y bueh, la base de datos debería estar en algún otro lugar